# Continuity of a function proof approach

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given a positive number b and a set E ⊆ R, let us say that a function f : E → R has
property X(b) on E provided that for each pair x, y ∈ E, |f(y) − f(x)| ≤ b|y − x|

How do I go about showing that if f has property X(b) on E then f is continuous on E?

what is the intuition here?

Comment: To show that $f$ is continuous on $E$, you have to show that $f$ is continuous
at every point $x_0 \in E$.  Intuitively, this means that for any other element
$y \in E$, as $y \to x_0, f(y) \to f(x_0)$.  Since $X(b)$ is assumed to hold
throughout $E$, you can compare the *continuity* requirement with
the premise that as $b|y-x_0| \to 0, |f(y) - f(x_0)| \to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ has property $X(b)$ on $E$ , then we can get that for any $\epsilon > 0$ , we can get a $0 <\delta < \frac \epsilon b $ set $|y-x| < \delta$ , follows
$$
|f(y) - f(x)| \le b|y-x| <\epsilon
$$
that's the definition of Uniform convergence

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me what it means for f(x) to have the property X(b)? what does X(b) mean? I am just starting out in analysis and am confused by perhaps trivial things

Comment: Isn't this the condition mentioned in your question?

Comment: I think that's means [Lipschitz condition][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity] and Lipschitz continuous ⊂ absolutely continuous .